# Call external API during validation (Rails)

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails, validation

I need to validate a value with data from an external API.
The easiest way would be to add a validation rule in my model, call the external API and do my check.

But it feels very dirty to call an API within my model.
(Also a lot of specs would fail due to missing api call mock).

What other options do I have within the normal rails stack?

What other options would I have, given I have a more complex model layer, such as service objects, repositories, etc.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "normal Rails stack"? Also, what do you mean by "more complex model layer" - things like service objects and repositories are usually implemented as plain old Ruby classes and are frequently used in Rails - there's absolutely nothing special about them, although there are some frameworks that give more structure to them.

Comment: By "normal rails stack" I mean Model, View, Controller classes. Nothing more.
So how would I implement this API check? Within my model? Within my controller?
There are not many options.

When I have a more sophisticated stack like service objects, form objects I have more options to implement this validation.
e.g. I could implement the validation within my service objects.

Comment: I think you're operating on some false assumptions. Why do you believe that you need to stick to only models, views, and controllers? I have never worked in a Rails application more than the most trivial that stuck to those three constructs. If you're constraining yourself artificially, you aren't going to have a good solution to this problem that will be robust in a production environment.

Comment: I do not restrict myself, I am just asking for different options I have with a "normal" rails stack and with a complex one.